# "Could not copy bindings to output directory" when building rocket with sqlite and podman

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, podman, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

###### A bit of context:

I'm developing in vscode. I'm using remote containers but instead of docker I'm using podman. It's the first time that I'm transitioning to podman, so I'm aware I lack knowledge about it. Hopefully you can help me.

I'm creating a small API that uses postgres for storing all needed information. I managed to set it all up, migrations and what not. It runs great.

###### The problem

I got my first contact, and I want to get my first test rolling. For that, I want to use SQLite in memory database, to avoid having to deal with temporary databases and such.
For doing this, I'm doing this steps:

1. I'm adding `sqlite` to my list of features in the `cargo.toml` file for `diesel`:

```
diesel = { version = "1.4.8", features = ["postgres", "sqlite", "uuidv07"] }
```

2. I'm creating a new struct `TestDBConn` that uses SQLite connection from `diesel` instead of Postgres:

```
pub struct TestDbConn(diesel::SqliteConnection);
```

3. With only this, I'm trying to compile my solution again with `cargo build`

This is when I get the following message:

```
Compiling libsqlite3-sys v0.22.2
error: failed to run custom build command for `libsqlite3-sys v0.22.2`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/workspace/target/debug/build/libsqlite3-sys-55c095f61869bd3c/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SQLITE3_LIB_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SQLITE3_STATIC
  cargo:link-target=sqlite3
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SQLITE3_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SQLITE3_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SQLITE3_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SYSROOT
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SQLITE3_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SQLITE3_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=sqlite3
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SQLITE3_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SQLITE3_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'Could not copy bindings to output directory: Os { code: 1, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Operation not permitted" }', /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libsqlite3-sys-0.22.2/build.rs:348:37
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

###### Current investigation direction

After googling and trying different stuff, I came to this realizations:

- SQLite3 for rust uses `bindgen` to generate binding for `C`
- The previous process needs to create those given bindings somewhere
- the `bindgen`library allows to overwrite the `OUT_DIR` environmental variable to allow to customize the output of given bindings
- When trying to do so via `OUT_DIR=/workspace/ cargo build`, I'm getting the exact same error, even though I have permission over the `/workspace/` directory with the `vscode` user
- I'm having the *feeling* that this could be related to podman. I suspect that since podman doesn't run the container as root by default, `bindgen` is trying to output the giving bindings to a directory where I have no permissions

Any ideas of what could this be?

**EDIT**: I've verified that if I change podman with docker, everything runs perfectly. So the question still stands. How to deal with containers not being root and this scenario?

Comment: I can't see any actual error message `could not copy bindings` in the text you copied - is that what is actually output, or is the above text all you can see?

Comment: @harmic its near the bottom, starts with "thread 'main' panicked at ..."

Comment: indeed. At the very bottom when showing the reason for panicking

Comment: More or less the same thing happens when building in WSL when the code is on an NTFS partition.